action.devices.traits.ColorSetting colorTemperatureRange Unable to echo in google home app
sync response
{"payload":{"agentUserId":"cn-C2341","devices":[{"attributes":{"commandOnlyOnOff":false,"queryOnlyOnOff":false,"colorTemperatureRange":{"temperatureMinK":2000,"temperatureMaxK":9000}},"customData":{"deviceKey":"VDU33779","pkDkId":"608","productKey":"p11qQ1"},"id":"p11qQ1-VDU33779","name":{"defaultNames":["3779"],"name":"3779","nicknames":["3779"]},"otherDeviceIds":[{"deviceId":"p11qQ1-VDU33779"}],"traits":["action.devices.traits.OnOff","action.devices.traits.ColorSetting"],"type":"action.devices.types.LIGHT","willReportState":true}]}}

query response
{"payload":{"devices":{"p11qQ1-VDU33779":{"online":true,"color":{"temperatureK":3000},"status":"SUCCESS","on":true}}}}

I reported the color temperature value according to the document, but the Google Home app panel cannot echo the color temperature I reported. Does it mean the echo function is not supported or my json is wrong?
Looking forward to helping me find out whether it is a problem with json or a problem with document understanding.
